# Writing Parquet file in standalone mode works..multiple worker mode fails

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, parquet, spark-jobserver

In Spark, version 1.6.1 (code is in Scala 2.10), I  am trying to write a data frame to a Parquet file:

```scala
import sc.implicits._
val triples = file.map(p => _parse(p, " ", true)).toDF() 
triples.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("hdfs://some.external.ip.address:9000/tmp/table.parquet")
```

When I do it in development mode, everything works fine. It also works fine if I setup a master and one worker in standalone mode in a docker environment (separate docker containers) on the same machine. It fails when I try to execute it on a cluster (1 master, 5 workers). If I set it up local on the master it also works.

When I try to execute it, I get following stacktrace:

```json
{
    "duration": "18.716 secs",
    "classPath": "LDFSparkLoaderJobTest2",
    "startTime": "2016-07-18T11:41:03.299Z",
    "context": "sql-context",
    "result": {
      "errorClass": "org.apache.spark.SparkException",
      "cause": "Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, curry-n3): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:147)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:113)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:112)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetRelation.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.abortTask$1(WriterContainer.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n\nDriver stacktrace:",
        "stack":[
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)",
          "scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)",
          "scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)",
          "scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)",
          "org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)",
          "org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)",
          "org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)",
          "org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)",
          "org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1922)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)",
          "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)",
          "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:334)",
          "LDFSparkLoaderJobTest2$.readFile(SparkLoaderJob.scala:55)",
          "LDFSparkLoaderJobTest2$.runJob(SparkLoaderJob.scala:48)",
          "LDFSparkLoaderJobTest2$.runJob(SparkLoaderJob.scala:18)",
          "spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:268)",
          "scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)",
          "scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)",
          "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)",
          "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)",
          "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"
        ],
        "causingClass": "org.apache.spark.SparkException",
        "message": "Job aborted."
    },
    "status": "ERROR",
    "jobId": "54ad3056-3aaa-415f-8352-ca8c57e02fe9"
}
```

**Notes:**

- The job is submitted via the Spark Jobserver.
- The file that needs to be converted to a Parquet file is 15.1 MB in size.

**Question:**

- Is there something I am doing wrong (I followed [the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files))
- Or is there  another way I can create the Parquet file, so all my workers have access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your stand alone setup only one worker is working with `ParquetRecordWriter`. so it worked fine.
- In case of real test i.e. **cluster (1 master, 5 workers).** with `ParquetRecordWriter` it will fail since you are concurrently writing with multiple workers...

[image]

pls try below.

```
 import sc.implicits._
    val triples = file.map(p => _parse(p, " ", true)).toDF() 
    triples.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("hdfs://some.external.ip.address:9000/tmp/table.parquet")
```

pls. see [SaveMode.Append   "append"    When saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already exists, contents of the DataFrame are expected to be appended to existing data.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had not exactly the same, but similar issues writing dataframes to parquet files in cluster mode. Those problems disappeared when deleteing the file, just before writing, using this convenience function 'write(..)' :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
..

def main(arg: Array[String]) {

    ..
    val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    ..

    def write(df:DataFrame, fn:String ) = {
        val op1=s"hdfs:///user/you/$fn"
        fs.delete(new Path(op1))
        df.write.parquet(op1)
    }
```

Give it a go, tell me if it works for you...